# Code-first migrations with an existing database with new dbsets

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, signalr, database-migration

I am developing a team chat. I created a SQL Server database and used `DbSet(User)` to define users and `DbSet(Room)` to define chat channels. I also added a many-to-many relationship using a third table, `DbSet(UserRooms)`.

Now I need to transfer everything to the MySQL Server database, where there are already some tables, and the most important of them is the managers table - which describes users. How can I use code-first to migrate everything as it was with the already existing table managers. And connect it many-to-many with rooms via `UserRooms`?